# 2 dimensional dynamic container qt

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic, containers

i'm writing kmeans algorithm. I need some 2d dynamic container to store groups of points.
Here some code

```
void KMeans::initialPartitionPoints()
{
    QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
    qsrand((uint)time.msec());
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfClusters(); i++)
    {
        qint64 randomValue = qrand() % _points->size();
        _centroids.push_back(new Centroid(_points->at(randomValue)));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < _points->size(); i++)
    {
        int cluster;
        qreal bestDistance = std::numeric_limits<qreal>::max();
        qreal distance;
        for (int j = 0; j < _centroids.size(); j++)
        {
            distance = _distanceMeasure->calculateDistance(_centroids.at(j), _points->at(i));
            if (distance < bestDistance)
            {
                bestDistance = distance;
                cluster = j;
            }
        }
        WHAT HERE TO STORE i POINT IN j GROUP?
    }
}
```

`_centroids` - is a list of points which are centers of the groups

`_points` - is a list of all points

Now how can i make something like `QList< QList<Point*> > _clusters` to store points in clusters where number of column is given in constructor and number of elements (rows) for each column is unknown. I mean how can i initialize first QList and set number of elements and then how can i use the second QList as dynamic (auto resize) container `(QList::append())`?

`cluster` is a group number where `_centroids[cluster]` is the same group like this one `_clusters[cluster][somePoint]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QList< QList<Point*> >`, it will work. You need to add each item to all lists manually one by one.

But I think you should use QVector instead of QList if you don't need to insert items at arbitrary positions and remove arbitrary items from lists. QVector can be easily resized using `resize()`. Getting and setting elements by index is faster. Memory consuming is lower.

Also consider using `Point` instead of `Point*` as a template type. Automatic memory managing should be used whenever possible.

Example:

```
QVector< QVector<Point> > matrix(row_count);
for(int row = 0; row < row_count; i++) {
  matrix[row].resize(column_count);
}
//...
matrix[row][column] = some_value;
```